# CakePHP with Homestead

Tags: cakephp, nginx, vagrant, homestead

I'm trying to do some cakePHP development using my existing homestead
installation I use for Laravel.

I can get the application running but it says that 
'URL rewriting is not properly configured on your server.'

I tried to use the instructions to configure nginx but did not have much luck.

Has anyone gotten url rewriting to work, or can point me at any sources?

I know their is a vagrant setup for cakephp, but I'd rather continue to use homestead if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSH into your Homestead VM.

Edit `/etc/nginx/sites-available/your-site.app` and add `/webroot` to the line that looks like: `root "/home/vagrant/your-site";` so that it looks like `root "/home/vagrant/your-site/webroot";`

Restart nginx with: `sudo service nginx restart`

Your should find your CakePHP pages can find their static content.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about homestead, other than it is a vagrant box. I would suggest using a box that was tailored for cakephp:

https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/vagrant-chef

This is an article on how to get that set up correctly:

http://josediazgonzalez.com/2014/12/02/designing-a-store-application-in-cakephp/